# Create function, return trigger

Tags: sql, oracle, triggers

The goal is to turn my active columns to say yes or no based on the values 1 and 0. Also, to auto update with the trigger. When i update my table it won't show the yes or no values in the new table.

```
    CREATE TABLE Detailed_customers(
customer_id integer,
first_name varchar(20),
last_name varchar(20),
active varchar(3),
rental_date timestamp,
return_date timestamp,
last_update timestamp);

CREATE TABLE Summary_customers(
customer_id int,
active varchar(3),
rental_date timestamp,
return_date timestamp);
```

C.

```
SELECT customer.customer_id, customer.first_name, customer.last_name, customer.active, rental.rental_date, rental.return_date, rental.last_update
FROM customer
JOIN rental on customer.customer_id = rental.customer_id;
```

D.

```
SELECT first_name, last_name, active, rental_date, return_date, store.store_id
FROM customer
INNER JOIN rental
ON customer.customer_id = rental.customer_id
INNER JOIN store
ON store.store_id = customer.store_id
WHERE active = 1
group by customer.first_name, customer.last_name, customer.active, rental.rental_date, rental.return_date, store.store_id
order by store.store_id asc;
```

E.

```
CREATE TRIGGER Detailed_update
AFTER UPDATE
ON Detailed_customers
FOR EACH STATEMENT
EXECUTE PROCEDURE active_status();
```

F.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE refreshed_data()
LANGUAGE PLPGSQL
AS
$$
BEGIN
DELETE FROM Detailed_customers;
DELETE FROM Summary_customers;

INSERT INTO Detailed_customers
SELECT customer.customer_id, first_name, last_name, active, rental_date, return_date, store.store_id
FROM customer
INNER JOIN rental
ON customer.customer_id = rental.customer_id
INNER JOIN store
ON store.store_id = customer.store_id
WHERE active = 1, store_id = 1
group by customer.customer_id, customer.first_name, customer.last_name, customer.active, rental.rental_date, rental.return_date, store.store_id
order by customer.first_name asc;

INSERT INTO Summary_customers
SELECT customer.customer_id, active, rental.rental_date, rental.rental_date
FROM customer
INNER JOIN rental
ON customer.customer_id = rental.customer_id
INNER JOIN store
ON store.store_id = customer.store_id
WHERE active = 1, store_id=1
group by customer.customer_id, customer.active, rental.rental_date, rental.return_date;

END;
$$;
```

```
CALL refreshed_data();
SELECT * FROM Summary_customers;
SELECT * FROM Detailed_customers;
```

Comment: Your trigger and procedure are not valid Oracle code. Are you sure you are not using PostgreSQL?

Answer (score 0):

As a frame challenge, don't use tables and triggers. Use a `VIEW`:

```sql
CREATE VIEW Detailed_customers
SELECT DISTINCT
       customer.customer_id,
       first_name,
       last_name,
       CASE active WHEN 1 THEN 'YES' ELSE 'NO' END active,
       rental_date,
       return_date,
       store.store_id
FROM   customer
       INNER JOIN rental
       ON customer.customer_id = rental.customer_id
       INNER JOIN store
       ON store.store_id = customer.store_id
WHERE  store_id = 1
-- AND    active = 1
ORDER BY customer.first_name asc;
```

```
CREATE VIEW Summary_customers
SELECT DISTINCT
       customer.customer_id,
       CASE active WHEN 1 THEN 'YES' ELSE 'NO' END active,
       rental.rental_date,
       rental.rental_date
FROM   customer
       INNER JOIN rental
       ON customer.customer_id = rental.customer_id
       INNER JOIN store
       ON store.store_id = customer.store_id
WHERE  store_id=1
-- AND    active = 1
;
```